# Pycharm Window Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: python, pygame, chess

I followed a Youtube tutorial for creating a Chess engine in Python code for code but it will not work in Pycharm? I can see that the correct chess board has been created but only when I close the pop-up window. Initially it shows as a black screen, then when I close the window it briefly appears before shutting as well. So I know that the code is working as intended, but there is some other issue at hand.

Here is the code just in case it is helpful:

```
import pygame as p
from Chess import engine

WIDTH = HEIGHT = 800
DIMENSION = 8
SQ_SIZE = HEIGHT // DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 15
IMAGES = {}


def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK', 'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
    # any icon image can be accessed using ICONS['__']


def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = engine.State()
    loadImages()
    running = True
    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
    visualise(screen, gs)
    clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
    p.display.flip()


def visualise(screen, gs):
    drawBoard(screen)
    drawPieces(screen, gs.board)


def drawBoard(screen):
    colours = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("gray")]
    for row in range(DIMENSION):
        for column in range(DIMENSION):
            tile = colours[((row + column) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, tile, p.Rect(column * SQ_SIZE, row * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def drawPieces(screen, board):
    for row in range(DIMENSION):
        for column in range(DIMENSION):
            piece = board[row][column]
            if piece != "--":
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(column * SQ_SIZE, row * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

// engine.py file

class State():
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [
            ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bB", "bN", "bR"],
            ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
            ["wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wB", "wN", "wR"]]
        self.whiteToMove = True
        self.moveLog = []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to draw the scene and update the display **in** the application loop, not **after** the application loop:

```py
def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = engine.State()
    loadImages()
    running = True
    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False

    # INDENTATION
    #-->|
        visualise(screen, gs)
        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        p.display.flip()
```